# Singly-linked list library

Tags: c, unit-testing, linked-list, memory-management, library

This is sort of a follow-up to a post I created about 10 days ago, but I have completed the implementation: [Designing function prototypes for a singly-linked list API in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26331/designing-function-prototypes-for-a-singly-linked-list-api-in-c).

As I began to work on the implementation, I chose to change some of the functions and to move things around a little. This post includes source for the header, followed by the source code for the implementation.

There are 10 API functions.

Here is my number one concern: if I run Valgrind on a test file that does a lot of operations, I don't have any noticeable memory leaks, but Valgrind complains that `sllist_destroy()` performs an invalid `free()`. That is, it attempts to free something that is either already freed or not at the beginning of a heap block. This saddens me, as I cannot figure out why this is occurring. So please take careful notice of the `sllist_destroy()` function.

I'm also interested in opinions on opaque versus non-opaque. I have left the structs visible in the header for now, but I'm open to suggestions.

The third thing I'd like to have some feedback on is return points. I don't know how sane my choices are there, as I know some people advocate single exit points for functions.

**Header:** Please note that I am using Doxygen for documentation, so if you see something unfamiliar in my comments, it is because it is Doxygen syntax.

`sllist.h`

```
#ifndef SLLIST_H
#define SLLIST_H

/**
 * @file sllist.h
 * @brief Stuctures and functions for a singly-linked list API.
 *
 * The user is provided with several different functions to manipulate lists 
 * and associated data.
 */

/**
 * The node structure.
 *
 * The purpose of this structure is to actually hold the data or "payload" to be
 * stored in the list. The nodes are connected sequentially, and thus each node
 * requires a second field to store the address of the next node.
 */
struct lnode {
        void *data;
        struct lnode *next;
};
/**
 * The list structure.
 *
 * Metadata is contained here. A pointer to the first and last nodes in the list
 * allows for several operations to be performed more quickly. There is also
 * another pointer-to-node member variable for storing the location of a
 * "current" or active node that presumably will have operations performed on
 * it. Finally there is a size variable containing the total number of nodes.
 * Note that the first index of the list is considered index zero.
 */
struct sllist {
        struct lnode *head;
        struct lnode *tail;
        struct lnode *current;
        int size;
};
/**
 * Create a new list.
 *
 * Returns a pointer to a new, empty list. If allocation fails, returns NULL.
 */
struct sllist* sllist_create(void);

/**
 * Destroy a list.
 *
 * Frees the memory of the list struct and all associated nodes.
 */
void sllist_destroy(struct sllist *sllist);

/**
 * Prepend a node to the list:
 *
 * Adds a node to the front of the list. If allocation fails, returns -1,
 * otherwise returns 0.
 */
int sllist_push_front(struct sllist *sllist, void *data);

/**
 * Append node to a list.
 *
 * Adds a node to the end of the list. If allocation fails, returns -1,
 * otherwise returns 0.
 */
int sllist_push_back(struct sllist *sllist, void *data);

/**
 * Extract the first node.
 *
 * Remove the first node from the linked list, save a pointer to the data, free
 * the node (but do not free the data itself), and return a pointer to the data
 * so that it can be used. If the list is empty, returns NULL.
 */
void* sllist_pop_front(struct sllist *sllist);

/**
 * Extract the last node.
 *
 * Remove the last node from the linked list, save a pointer to the data, free
 * the node (but do not free the data itself), and return a pointer to the data
 * so that it can be used. If the list is empty, returns NULL.
 */
 void* sllist_pop_back(struct sllist *sllist);

/**
 * Step through a list.
 *
 * Changes the current node to the node after the current node. Returns 1 if
 * the current node is NULL.
 */

int sllist_step(struct sllist *sllist);

/**
 * Access data by index.
 *
 * Returns a pointer to the payload of the node at the location specified by the
 * passed index value. The passed index value is interpreted as an offset from
 * index zero, the first node of the list. Returns NULL if the list is empty or
 * the index is out of range.
 */
void* sllist_read_index(struct sllist *sllist, int index);

/**
 * Insert a node after the node at the specified index.
 *
 * Adds a node after the passed node. If allocation fails, returns -1. If the
 * node doesn't exist in the list, returns 1. Otherwise, returns 0.
 */
int sllist_insert_after(struct sllist *sllist, int index, void *data);

/**
 * Extract a node after the node at the specified index.
 *
 * Remove the specified node from the linked list, save a pointer to the data,
 * free the node (but do not free the data itself), and return a pointer to the
 * data so that it can be used. If the list is empty or the node doesn't exist
 * in the list, returns NULL. Attempting to extract after the tail will also
 * return NULL.
 */
void* sllist_extract_after(struct sllist *sllist, int index);

#endif
```

**Implementation:**

`sllist.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sllist.h"

struct sllist* sllist_create(void)
{
        struct sllist *sllist;
        sllist = malloc(sizeof(struct sllist));
        if (sllist != NULL) {
                sllist->head = NULL;
                sllist->tail = NULL;
                sllist->current = NULL;
                sllist->size = 0;
        }
        return sllist;
}

void sllist_destroy(struct sllist *sllist)
{
        struct lnode *save_next;
        sllist->current = sllist->head;
        while(sllist->current != NULL) {
                save_next = sllist->current->next;
                free(sllist->current->data);
                free(sllist->current);
                sllist->current = save_next;
        }
        free(sllist);
}

int sllist_push_front(struct sllist *sllist, void *data)
{
        struct lnode *lnode;
        lnode = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
        if (lnode == NULL)
                return -1;
        lnode->data = data;
        lnode->next = sllist->head;
        sllist->head = lnode;
        if (sllist->size == 0)
                sllist->tail = lnode;
        sllist->size++;
        return 0;

}

int sllist_push_back(struct sllist *sllist, void *data)
{
        struct lnode *lnode;
        lnode = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
        if (lnode ==NULL)
                return -1;
        lnode->data = data;
        lnode->next = NULL;
        if (sllist->size == 0) {
                sllist->head = lnode;
                sllist->tail = lnode;
        } else {
                sllist->tail->next = lnode;
                sllist->tail = lnode;
        }
        sllist->size++;
        return 0;
}

void* sllist_pop_front(struct sllist *sllist)
{
    if (sllist->size == 0)
        return NULL;
        void* data = sllist->head->data;
        struct lnode *save_head = sllist->head;
    if (sllist->size == 1) {
                sllist->head = NULL;
        sllist->tail = NULL;
                //Clear current since it shouldn't be used.
        sllist->current = NULL;
    } else {
        sllist->head = sllist->head->next;
    }
        free(save_head);
    sllist->size--;
    return data;
}

void* sllist_pop_back(struct sllist *sllist)
{
        if (sllist->size == 0)
                return NULL;
        void *data = sllist->tail->data;
        struct lnode *save_tail = sllist->tail;
        if (sllist->size == 1) {
                sllist->head = NULL;
                sllist->tail = NULL;
                //Clear current since it shouldn't be used.
                sllist->current = NULL;
        } else {
                struct lnode *new_tail = sllist->head;
                while(new_tail->next->next != NULL)
                        new_tail = new_tail->next;
                sllist->tail = new_tail;
                sllist->tail->next = NULL;
        }
        free(save_tail);
        sllist->size--;
        return data;
}

int sllist_step(struct sllist *sllist)
{
        if (sllist->current == NULL)
                return 1;
        else {
                sllist->current = sllist->current->next;
                return 0;
        }
}

void* sllist_read_index(struct sllist *sllist, int index)
{
        if ( ((sllist->size - index - 1) < 0 ) || (index < 0) )
                return NULL;
        struct lnode *target;
        target = sllist->head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                target = target->next;
        return (target->data);
}

int sllist_insert_after(struct sllist *sllist, int index, void *data)
{
        if ( ((sllist->size - index - 1) < 0 ) || (index < 0) )
                return 1;
        struct lnode *target;
        target = sllist->head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                target = target->next;
        struct lnode *lnode;
        lnode = malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
        if (lnode == NULL)
                return -1;
        lnode->data = data;
        lnode->next = target->next;
        target->next = lnode;
        if (index == sllist->size - 1) //if inserting after tail
                sllist->tail = lnode;
        sllist->size++;
        return 0;

}

void* sllist_extract_after(struct sllist *sllist, int index)
{
        if ( ((sllist->size - index - 2) < 0 ) || (index < 0) )
                return NULL;
        struct lnode *target;
        target = sllist->head;
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                target = target->next;
        if (index == sllist->size - 1) //if extracting tail
                sllist->tail = target;
        void *data = target->next->data;
        struct lnode *save_obsolete = target->next;
        target->next = target->next->next;
        free(save_obsolete);
        sllist->size--;
        return data;
}
```

If you've made it this far, all I ask is for your most exacting criticism.

As requested, here is the portion of do-nothing code that generates the Valgrind error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sllist.h"

int main(void)
{
        struct sllist *nums;
        nums = sllist_create();
        int *number;
        for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
                number = malloc(sizeof(int));
                *number = i;
                sllist_push_front(nums, number);
                sllist_push_back(nums, number);
        } 

        number = sllist_pop_front(nums); //testing multiple different things
        free(number);
        number = sllist_pop_back(nums);
        free(number);
        sllist_destroy(nums);
}
```

Further, if anyone is interested in seeing the glib-2.0 testing API in action, I used it in this project to see how it works. Here is my unit test code:

`unit.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include "sllist.h"

/* Types of lists to test:
 * empty lists
 * lists with 1 element
 * lists with 2 elements
 * lists with multiple elements
 */

//Singly linked list fixture. A wrapper for sllist struct, for testing.
struct sll_fix {
        struct sllist *sllist;
};

//Prepare fixture for testing an empty list.
static void sll_setup(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_f->sllist = sllist_create();
}

static void sll_teardown(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sllist_destroy(sll_f->sllist);
}

//Prepare fixture for testing push_front operation.
static void sll_setup_pf(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_f->sllist = sllist_create();
        int *testp;
        testp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                testp[i] = i * 10;
        sllist_push_front(sll_f->sllist, testp);
}

//Prepare fixture for testing push_back operation.
static void sll_setup_pb(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
    sll_f->sllist = sllist_create();
    int *testp;
    testp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            testp[i] = i * 10;
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp);
}

//Prepare fixture for testing pop operation.
static void sll_setup_pop(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_f->sllist = sllist_create();
        int *testp_1;
        int *testp_2;
        int *testp_3;
    testp_1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    testp_2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    testp_3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        testp_1[i] = i * 10;
        testp_2[i] = i * 20;
        testp_3[i] = i * 30;
    }
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp_1);
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp_2);
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp_3);
}

//Prepare fixture for testing step operation.
static void sll_setup_step(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
    sll_f->sllist = sllist_create();
    int *testp_1;
    int *testp_2;
        int *testp_3;
    testp_1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    testp_2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    testp_3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        testp_1[i] = i * 10;
        testp_2[i] = i * 20;
        testp_3[i] = i * 30;
    }
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp_1);
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp_2);
    sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp_3);
}

//Prepare fixture for testing a lengthy list (100 elements.)
static void sll_setup_lengthy(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_f->sllist = sllist_create();
        int *testp;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                testp = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                        testp[j] = j * 10;
                sllist_push_back(sll_f->sllist, testp);

        }
}

//Procedure for testing an empty list
static void check_create(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup(sll_f, ignored);
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->head == NULL);
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->tail == NULL);
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->current == NULL);
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->size == 0);
}

//Procedure for testing a push_front operation on an empty list.
static void check_pf(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_pf(sll_f, ignored);
        int *int_arr;
    int_arr = sll_f->sllist->head->data;
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->size == 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            g_assert(int_arr[i] == i * 10);
}

//Procedure for testing a push_back operation on an empty list
static void check_pb(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_pb(sll_f, ignored);
        int *int_arr;
        int_arr = sll_f->sllist->head->data;
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->size == 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == i * 10);

}

//Procedure for testing a pop_front operation on a list with 3 elements.
static void check_popf(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_pop(sll_f, ignored);
        int* int_arr;
        int loop_ctr = 1;
        while ((int_arr = sllist_pop_front(sll_f->sllist))) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        g_assert(int_arr[i] == 10 * loop_ctr * i);
                loop_ctr++;
        }
}

//Procedure for testing a pop_back operation on a list with 3 elements.
static void check_popb(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_pop(sll_f, ignored);
        int* int_arr;
        int loop_ctr = 3;
        while((int_arr = sllist_pop_back(sll_f->sllist))) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        g_assert(int_arr[i] == 10 * loop_ctr * i);
                loop_ctr--;
        }
}

//Procedure for testing a step operation on a list with 3 elements.
static void check_step(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_step(sll_f, ignored);
        int *int_arr_1;
        int *int_arr_2;
        int *int_arr_3;
        int_arr_1 = sll_f->sllist->head->data;
        int_arr_2 = sll_f->sllist->head->next->data;
        int_arr_3 = sll_f->sllist->head->next->next->data;
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->size == 3);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                g_assert(int_arr_1[i] == i * 10);
                g_assert(int_arr_2[i] == i * 20);
                g_assert(int_arr_3[i] == i * 30);
        }
        int *int_arr;
        int loop_ctr = 1;
        sll_f->sllist->current = sll_f->sllist->head;
        while(sll_f->sllist->current != NULL) {
                int_arr = sll_f->sllist->current->data;
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        g_assert(int_arr[i] == 10 * loop_ctr * i);
                sllist_step(sll_f->sllist);
                loop_ctr++;
        }

}

//Procedure for testing a read_index operation on a list with 100 elements.
static void check_ri(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_lengthy(sll_f, ignored);
        int *int_arr;
        sll_f->sllist->current = sll_f->sllist->head;
        for(int i = 0; i < sll_f->sllist->size; i++) {
                int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, i);
                for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                        g_assert(int_arr[j] == j * 10);
                sllist_step(sll_f->sllist);
        }
}

//Procedure for testing an insert_after operation on a list with 100 elements.
static void check_ia(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_lengthy(sll_f, ignored);
        int *int_arr;
        int_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                int_arr[i] = 314159 * i;
        g_assert(!sllist_insert_after(sll_f->sllist, 0, int_arr));
        g_assert(!sllist_insert_after(sll_f->sllist, 1, int_arr));
        g_assert(!sllist_insert_after(sll_f->sllist, 50, int_arr));
        g_assert(!sllist_insert_after(sll_f->sllist, 102, int_arr));
        int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == i * 10);
        int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == 314159 * i);
        int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, 2);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == 314159 * i);
        int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, 51);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == 314159 * i);
        int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, 52);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == i * 10);
        int_arr = sllist_read_index(sll_f->sllist, 103);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                g_assert(int_arr[i] == 314159 * i);

}

//Procedure for testing an extract_after operation on a list with 100 elements.
static void check_ea(struct sll_fix *sll_f, gconstpointer ignored)
{
        sll_setup_lengthy(sll_f, ignored);
        int *int_arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
        int_arr = sllist_extract_after(sll_f->sllist, 98);
        g_assert(sll_f->sllist->size == 99);
        g_assert(int_arr != NULL);
        int_arr = sllist_extract_after(sll_f->sllist, 98);
        g_assert(int_arr == NULL);
}

//Run tests in the order they appear in this file.
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        g_test_init(&argc, &argv, NULL);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_create test", struct sll_fix, NULL, sll_setup,
                                                        check_create,
                                                        sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_push_front test", struct sll_fix, NULL, 
                                                        sll_setup_pf, check_pf,
                                                        sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_push_back test", struct sll_fix, NULL,
                                                        sll_setup_pb, check_pb,
                                                        sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_pop_front test", struct sll_fix, NULL, 
                                                        sll_setup_pop,
                                                        check_popf,
                                                        sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_pop_back test", struct sll_fix, NULL,
                                                        sll_setup_pop,
                                                        check_popb,
                                                        sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_step test", struct sll_fix, NULL, sll_setup_step,
                                                        check_step,
                                                        sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_read_index test", struct sll_fix, NULL,
                                                        sll_setup_lengthy, 
                                                        check_ri, sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_insert_after test", struct sll_fix, NULL,
                                                        sll_setup_lengthy, 
                                                        check_ia, sll_teardown);
        g_test_add("/test/sll_extract_after test", struct sll_fix, NULL,
                                                        sll_setup_lengthy, 
                                                        check_ea, sll_teardown);
        return g_test_run();
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with _sllist_destroy_.  Do you have a minimal program that uses your library to elicit the Valgrind complaint?  If you do, could you please attach it?

Comment: Hi Wayne, I've added the code that causes the invalid free() error. Thanks for your time.

Comment: OK, I see the memory error.  I'll amend my answer.  By the way, I can tell you from personal experience that if you run valgrind with `valgrind test` instead of `valgrind ./test`, you will be horribly confused as to why it doesn't seem to have any memory problems.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a clean and well documented API: There is little reason to have to read to the code to know how to use it.  The only thing I see missing from the comment is any mention of what happens to the cursor (*sllist.current*) when the list is modified.

The memory error is because your code is pushing the same node onto the list twice:

```
sllist_push_front(nums, number);
sllist_push_back(nums, number);
```

In order for that to work, the second push will need its own malloc.

Multiple return points are only a problem if a function is too large for them to be easy to spot.  The solution: Don't write large functions.  Your functions are not too large, so it's not a problem.

The only suggestion I have would be not minor surgery, but a complete redesign.  I'll mention it here not because it has anything to do with your question, but because you may not have considered it.  Below the fold:

---

If you are able to switch to a doubly linked with with a dummy (root) node to serve as the head/tail, then linked list code can be simplified considerably, and most operations--such as insertion before or after an arbitrary node, or removing a node from a list--can be done very efficiently without any linear searches over the list, and with very little conditional logic.

```
struct Node {
  struct void *data;
  struct Node *prev;
  struct Node *next;
};
```

A special node is the "dummy" node, which serves as both the head and tail of the list (in this sketch I will ignore dynamic allocation).  The root node is initialized like so:

```
void init_list(Node * node) {
  node->prev = node;
  node->next = next;
  node->data = NULL;     
}
```

The dummy/root node always has a NULL data pointer.  A non-dummy node always has a *non*-NULL data pointer.

insertion after an arbitrary node is trivial:

```
void insert_after(Node * pred, Node * node) {
  node->pred = pred;
  node->next = pred->next;
  pred->next->pred = node;
  pred->next = node;
}
```

insertion before an arbitrary node:

```
void insert_before(Node * next, Node * node) {
  insert_after(next->pred, node);
}
```

The node being inserted before or after can be the dummy (root) node--the same logic works.  Whether inserting at the head or tail, or before or after an arbitrary node, no list traversal is needed.

Return true if the node is a dummy (root) node.  This is used to detect the end of list:

```
bool dummy_node(Node * node) {
  node->data == NULL;
}
```

One advantage of this structure is that no separate cursor (*current node*) is needed.  Every node pointer is automatically a cursor.

```
Node * next_node(Node * node) {return node->next;}
Node * prev_node(Node * node) {return node->prev;}

Node * node = next_node(dummy);
while(!dummy_node(node))
  node = next_node(node);
```

The big disadvantage of this approach, compared to yours, is that a cursor is not integrated into the list.  That means a cursor cannot be automatically invalidated when the list changes, as your code does.  In every other way, I believe this approach to be simpler and more efficient to implement.  It is, however, necessarily a complete redesign of the API.  That's why it is out of scope in answering your original question.

Comment: Thank you for you well-reasoned reply. I am glad that you pointed out that the documentation makes no mention of what happens to the `current` node. I will add this to the documentation. You have also brought to my attention that in the function `sllist_extract_after()` I forget to check whether I need to invalidate `current`, since my intention was to assign a NULL pointer to any invalid node references to make errors more obvious. Regarding your redesign, I have definitely given it much thought, and I actually intended from the beginning to do a full API suite involving dllists, hashes, etc.

Comment: About the memory error: Wow, now I feel silly. I don't know why I didn't realize that. I just wrote the test very quickly and thought, hm, I'll just reuse this same data. Yeah, thanks for keeping me sane.

Comment: @oddlogic, I'll bet you didn't feel as silly as I felt when I realized I had been running Valgrind on a Unix utility instead of your code. :)  I'm just glad we got it sorted out.  By the way, your code caused gcc to emit _no_ warnings even on the strict settings I prefer.  Nice job!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I usually compile with -Wall as well. Also, I didn't even know there was a utility called 'test', but I typed 'man test', and there it was!

Answer (score 1):

The code looks nice and compiles cleanly.  One thing that I guess you have
heard before is to use braces on conditions (etc) even when strictly unnecessary.

```
if (lnode == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

Yes, it is ugly, but it is generally accepted as being safer. I hate doing it too,
but sometimes ugly really is better...

---

I prefer to see variables initialised immediately where possible, so for example:

```
struct sllist *sllist;
sllist = malloc(sizeof(struct sllist));
```

is written:

```
struct sllist *sllist = malloc(sizeof(struct sllist));
```

---

In  `sllist_pop_back`, I'd prefer to see the loop that finds the end of the
list extracted into a separate static inline function.

---

Your last three functions all contain an expression that determines whether
`index` exceeds the list size:

```
if ( ((sllist->size - index - 1) < 0 ) || (index < 0) )
```

Wouldn't it be easier to say:

```
if ((index >= sllist->size) || (index < 0))
```

---

Your last three functions all contain code to find a given entry in the list:

```
struct lnode *target = sllist->head;
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    target = target->next;
}
```

This should really be extracted into a static function.

---

Nits:

- `sllist_read_index` return statement has brackets. No other function has
  them.
- I see no purpose in the `current` field. Nothing really uses it.
- The structures are not opaqe (and hence are open to client manipulation)
- You free all of the data pointers when destroying the list, which assumes
  that the data was dynamically allocated.  Best to state this restriction in
  the interface.
- How does the client determine which 'index' to use in those functions taking
  an index?

Comment: All solid advice. I'll start with the "nits": I believe my rationale for 'index' is that the user conceivably have their own reasons for accessing a particular index. For example, if the list is created with some kind of order, say a list of prime numbers or something, index 6 would contain the 7th prime number.
I think I am going to add some accessor functions and move the structs into the implementation. This would make `current` more sensible because it would provide an opaque way to move through the list, via `sllist_step`.

Comment: The condition 
`if (abs(index) >= sllist->size)` treats negative values greater than or equal to `-index` as acceptable, but if I change it to 
`if ((abs(index) >= sllist->size) || (index < 0)` then I believe we've created a statement that more clearly expresses my intent than `if ( ((sllist->size - index - 1) < 0 ) || (index < 0) )` On the other hand, I then have to include `cmath.h`. I don't believe this is much of a problem, however. What are your thoughts? Everything else you've said I more or less totally agree with.

Comment: oops! Yes, `abs` is clearly wrong.  You could use `(unsigned) index >= sllist->size` but that will provoke a conversion warning. I will change the answer...